Match any time in the ISO 8601 format between 06:40:00 and 06:59:59 am (UTC)
Timestamp Parsing
You are Kaylee Walmsley, a security engineer at ComTech. The SOC has received security alerts every day for the past few weeks for an account (SVCnetops) logging into multiple endpoints from the same source. Each time it occurs, you contact the system owner and are told it is normal.
You noticed that the logins always occur around the same time, so you contact the system owner to ask how this account is used and you are told that they use a script that logs into a few endpoints at roughly the same time each day to collect information. Their time window is 06:40:00 am to 06:59:59 am (UTC), so any logins outside that time range would be considered suspicious.
You have started to create a rule to suppress these alerts in the SIEM, however, the SIEM does not support time ranges. Therefore, you must use regex in order to match the timestamps of the expected logins by the account.
So far, your rule looks like this:
Source IP address equals 192.168.5.13
Destination IP address equals 192.168.5.20 OR 192.168.5.21 OR 192.168.5.30
Username equals SVCnetops
Timestamp matches 
In order to complete the rule, you must create a regex that matches the following timestamps only (regardless of date):
06:40:00 am to 06:59:59 am (UTC)
The timestamp always appears in the logs in the ISO 8601 format, which looks like this:
2022-07-21T06:40:12.000Z
It is made up of the date in reverse (YYYY-MM-DD), followed by a "T" and then the time. The "Z" at the end indicates the UTC time zone.
The regex code has to match the timestamps:
Timestamp: 2020-06-01T06:52:46.000Z
Timestamp: 2006-02-28T06:41:44.000Z
Timestamp: 2011-03-08T06:50:21.000Z
Timestamp: 2014-01-09T06:54:42.000Z
Timestamp: 2007-04-04T06:59:46.000Z
Timestamp: 2010-08-20T06:55:41.000Z
Timestamp: 2016-02-26T06:57:45.000Z
Timestamp: 2017-12-16T06:53:22.000Z
Timestamp: 2007-04-23T06:44:22.000Z
Timestamp: 2008-10-19T06:51:56.000Z
Timestamp: 2005-09-07T06:44:11.000Z
Timestamp: 2022-02-07T06:41:46.000Z
Timestamp: 2013-07-24T06:56:36.000Z
Timestamp: 2012-03-08T06:58:20.000Z
Timestamp: 2014-08-16T06:48:37.000Z
Timestamp: 2015-07-02T06:44:16.000Z
Timestamp: 2020-02-26T06:58:59.000Z
Timestamp: 2022-03-05T06:40:46.000Z
Timestamp: 2016-04-15T06:49:17.000Z
Timestamp: 2016-10-15T06:53:42.000Z

But not these timestamps:
Timestamp: 2007-09-17T00:14:11.000Z
Timestamp: 2008-06-30T19:23:45.000Z
Timestamp: 2014-03-04T21:03:15.000Z
Timestamp: 2005-01-22T05:00:03.000Z
Timestamp: 2012-01-10T02:47:57.000Z
Timestamp: 2021-04-07T06:17:18.000Z
Timestamp: 2019-04-30T11:05:00.000Z
Timestamp: 2007-04-14T23:26:44.000Z
Timestamp: 2021-09-03T06:27:07.000Z
Timestamp: 2008-05-04T11:08:07.000Z
Timestamp: 2014-12-10T06:34:54.000Z
Timestamp: 2008-09-12T16:56:24.000Z
Timestamp: 2018-09-12T10:45:04.000Z
Timestamp: 2005-02-14T21:07:45.000Z
Timestamp: 2006-03-18T13:08:54.000Z
Timestamp: 2007-02-17T09:45:08.000Z
Timestamp: 2016-10-01T04:37:18.000Z
Timestamp: 2014-06-12T03:10:53.000Z
Timestamp: 2022-02-13T03:01:20.000Z
Timestamp: 2009-12-26T06:21:01.000Z
Timestamp: 2007-03-14T05:54:11.000Z
Timestamp: 2017-03-02T16:35:59.000Z
Timestamp: 2014-05-12T10:25:20.000Z
Timestamp: 2016-08-06T21:57:24.000Z
Timestamp: 2006-09-17T15:18:25.000Z

I tried: ^06:(4{0-9}|5{0-9}):{0-5}{0-9}$. This did not work.
I also tried: \d{4}(.\d{2}){2}(\s|T)(\d{2}.){2}\d{2}
(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
The ones that did have results were: (06:4[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]|06:59:[0-5][0-9])
(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
These got me close but I needed to make adjustments still.


As an alternative (assuming you are working with some programming language and not some config file etc.) I would suggest to just parse the line: split at space, then parse the whole ISO string (programming languages typically have that functionality built-in) and use the built-in date type to filter out the ones not within the desired range.

So you mean split the timestamps I am supposed to match and filter out the ones that don't match with the regular expression code?

Matching full ISO 8601 is non-trivial. For example, MM-DD can be Www-D. Z can be an offset. Which revision of the spec do you need to target? Do you actually only need to match precisely the format shown in your examples? Do you need to match/discard things that look like ISO 8601 but actually aren't valid? (eg. 2024-09-51)

For example, this regex is incomplete: ^([\+-]?\d{4}(?!\d{2}\b))((-?)((0[1-9]|1[0-2])(\3([12]\d|0[1-9]|3[01]))?|W([0-4]\d|5[0-2])(-?[1-7])?|(00[1-9]|0[1-9]\d|[12]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|6[1-6])))([T\s]((([01]\d|2[0-3])((:?)[0-5]\d)?|24\:?00)([\.,]\d+(?!:))?)?(\17[0-5]\d([\.,]\d+)?)?([zZ]|([\+-])([01]\d|2[0-3]):?([0-5]\d)?)?)?)?$

I need to directly match any time between 06:40:00 and 06:59:59

A better anchor to use would be a lookbehind pattern that asserts a match is preceded by a T:
(?<=T)06:[45]\d:\d{2}

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/Sou5nn/1

I tried this and it didn't work in giving me the timestamp range I wanted. Is there something else I can try in the regular expression programming language that can do the same?

Please give specific examples of which timestamps the regex isn't matching correctly. As the demo shows it does exactly match what you want to match in the sample input.
